# Cannot delete escape sequence from string

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following PHP code as to construct a string which will contain some emails:

```
$mailist.=$usermail."\n";
```

The $usermail variable is already initialised and $mailist variable has taken its value from MySQL database; its new value will be used for:

```
UPDATE REQUESTS SET teamails='$mailist' where ...";
```

Since I want to use the content of the field teamails as to show it inside a textarea and I want to separate each email with new line, I 've used "\n" with success.

However, when I want to delete an email from the field teamails I cannot delete the escape sequence. The result is to remain two or more escape sequences in a row and two or more blank lines appear among emails in the textarea. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
$usermail.="&#13;&#10;";
$mailist = str_replace($usermail,"",$mailist); 
$query="UPDATE REQUESTS SET teamails='$mailist' where ... ";
```

Do you know how to delete the escape "\n" along with the email?

Thank you very much

Comment: `$mailist = str_replace("\n", "", $mailist);` maybe?

Comment: There's no escape sequence in the string. The string just contains a newline character. The escape sequence is just how you type that in PHP source code.

Comment: BTW, get out of the practice of putting lists of things in a single database field. You should use a relation table that has one row per list member, and join with it.

Comment: You should normalize your database. Storing new-line separated lists in one field only leads to problems and makes it very hard to update, search, etc..

Answer (score 1):

First let me just say that this is bad db design - your columns should contain single piece of information.
Ideally you should have db schema like this:

```
Members(id, email ,...), Teams(id, ...), TeamsMails(id_member, id_team)
```

To answer your question you could try something like this:

```
$str = "aaa@bb.cc\nbbb@bb.cc\nddd@bb.cc";
$str = str_replace("bbb@bb.cc", "", $str);
$str = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $str);
```